# Asterisk (*) and plus (+) are not working in Notepad++ as a regular expression

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am using [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and learning regular expressions, but I am wondering why some of the meta characters are not working in the editor, that is, asterisk (*) and plus (+).

For example:

> The tree is looking awesome with leaves and flowers.

Regular expression: [tre*]

The above regular expression is not working in Notepad++ as expected.

Comment: Is your regular expression `[tre*]` or `tre*`?

Comment: My regular expression is [tre*]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **my purpose is to match `tre` and its *preceding* characters.**

Well in your example `The tree is looking awesome with leaves and flowers.` the word fragment `tre` is not *preceeded* by any characters in the same word, it is preceeded by characters which are part of earlier words. This makes it your question seem a bit ambiguous.

To match any characters followed by "t" then "r" then "e", I would use `.*tre`.

To match "t" then "r" then "e" followed by any characters, I would use `tre.*`.

To match a **word** beginning with "t" then "r" then "e", I would use `tre\w*`

> **My regular expression is [tre*]**

That matches a single character, the character matched can be any *one* of the four specified. Inside `[]` the metacharacter `*` is just treated like an ordinary character (because that is the most useful way for it to be treated in that context).

The brackets `[]` are for specifying one character to be found in the text that can have several possibilities. For example, if you want to match either of the words `Tree` or `tree` you could use `[Tt]ree` which means match a character that is either `T` or `t` followed by a second character that is `r` followed by a third character that is `e` followed by a fourth character that is `e`.

You could match `Tree` and `tree` using `.ree` but the `.` matches any single character so the RE would also match `free` and other words you might not want. `[]` provides a means for you to be more specific than `.` in specifying the values of a single character in the text which you want to match

Comment: Yes This is exactly what I was trying to solve. But Please explain one thing further in terms of notepad++ that, I was searching the word with square brackets like [tre*] and the editor matches character by character while I want the editor to match a complete word and tre\w* solved my problem.

Comment: @Rajper, see updated answer. For more info, I suggest using a search engine to find `regular expression tutorial`.

Comment: @rajper, for more info on regex, I recommend [MSDN's regex quick reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Basically, anything in between square brackets (`[]`) means: "*find any of the characters inside those brackets, I don't care which*". The only exception is when you have a hyphen (`-`), for instance `[A-Z]`, which means: "*find any character in between A and Z*", in my particular example it simply means "*find any character of the Latin alphabet*".

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick could you edit the question so it isn't ambigous anymore?

Answer (score 2):

`*` and `+` aren't meta characters when in a character class. This is true for regex in general, not only for Notepad++. `[a*+]` means *"match single `a`, `*` or `+`"*.

If you want to match any number of characters `t`, `r` or `e`, use `[tre]*`. It will match any of these:

```
tttrreerer
rrrrrr
er
t
(empty line)
```

If you want to match single `t`, single `r` or any number of `e`s, use `([tr]|e*)` or `(t|r|e*)`. This regex matches following lines:

```
t
r
eeeeeeeee
(empty line)
```

And won't match eg. `tre`.

Here's a [good regex tutorial](http://qntm.org/files/re/re.html).

Comment: Well, my purpose is to match tre and its preceding characters.
As you said in answer; It may be right but in terms of notepad++ it is not working even [tre]* that you had mentioned.

Comment: @Rajper Can you post few examples of strings you want to match?

Comment: String-1: The furniture of office is old.
I want to search literal 'office' for that I write a regex as [offic]* as the asterisk would add any character and office literal will be found but this is not working.

Comment: @Rajper `[offic]*` would match any sequence of zero or more characters `o`, `f`, `i`, `c`. For example `ofic` or `fcio` or `foiicffocicooeo` or empty string. Please read the tutorial I have linked.